# Matrix dimensions must agree matlab warning in a for cycle

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, find, cycle

i'm trying to use the find function but i keep receiving an error.

i have few variables
lat_rho3; 181x1 matrix
lon_rho2; 385x1 matrix
Clat; 579x1 matrix
Clon; 579x1 matrix

the next for cycle is to obtain the positions in lat_rho2 and lon_rho2 between the values of KL and MN respectively

```
for a=1
    l=1:579;
    f=1:579;
    K=Clat(l,1)-0.1;
    L=Clat(l,1)+0.1;
    M=(Clon(f,1)-0.1);
    N=(Clon(f,1)+0.1);
    
    D=find(lat_rho3>K & lat_rho3<L & lon_rho2>M & lon_rho2<N);
end
```

but i get this error:
Matrix dimensions must agree.

i tried to change positions, reshape but i simply can't make it work.

Comment: Generally it means that you're giving an operator two matrices or vectors with mismatched sizes. You should post your entire code rather than a snippet, though, because it's impossible to tell what lat_rho3, Clat, etc. dimensions are. Also I'm not sure that you need a for-loop for this because I don't see 'a' referenced within the loop.

Comment: i specifed the dimension but i think i did it in the title. Clat and Clon are 579x1 matrix and lat_rho3 & lon_rho2 are 385x1

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] for debugging help.